# What do the tools in options panel( like Tag Bevel )in edit mode do?

Tags: modeling, interface, selection-tools

[image: emphasized text]

I was trying to get to know everything in Blender and I came across the options tab in *Edit Mode* and there's whole bunch of options like *Tag Seam*, *Tag Bevel* etc.

I know how to use all the suffix functions (i.e every tool without "tag" ).But I am wondering if this has any specific function/usability.

So, if anyone has any idea can you please explain all those options(*Tag Seam*, *Tag Sharp*, *Tag Crease*, *Tag Bevel*)? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know those sound like the options in the `W` menu for use with the corresponding modifiers like *Bevel*, or *Subsurf*)

Comment: Thanks for the response man.But could you please clarify,what purpose the tools/options in W menu serve when used with corresponding modifier? Lets take SubSurf modifier as example,the suitable options I see for them is Shade smooth and flat.But these only save the time and/or trouble of going back to object mode.Or is there some other use that I seem to not know about?

Comment: I've been testing here I could not figure out what those options are really for. I know tagging edges from the `W` menu is used in parallel with modifiers to specify different transformation values for different parts of the model. Say the *Bevel Weight* can make different edges beveled a different distance without requiring multiple *Bevel* modifiers. Different *Crease* values will change how smoothed an edge is with a  *Subsurf* modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options in the *Options Panel* for tagging edges are the same as the *edges menu* with only a slight difference that I can see. Most notably in *Bevel* and *Crease*, in that the weight added is always at `1`.

- *Crease* marks edges for use with subsurf, with a weight of `1`
- *Bevel* marks edges for use with Bevel modifier, with a weight of `1`
- *Sharp* will mark edges sharp for edge split modifier
- *Seam* will mark seams for UV unwrap
- *Freestyle Edge Mark* will mark edges for use with Freestyle

To use the *Tag Bevel, Tag Crease , Tag Sharp, Tag Seam* tool, it is as simple as selecting each edge with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>